# How do you rewrite this script to use Facebook's current SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, syntax, facebook-javascript-sdk

The following line in a script gives an error about an incorrect version.  How do you rewrite this phrase to use Facebook's latest SDK?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if (!(0 < lb_l_ret.show_once && 1 == readCookie("arevico_lb") || 1 == readCookie("arevico_lb_ns"))) {
    var a = "",
        a = "" == lb_l_ret.fblocale ? "en_US" : lb_l_ret.fblocale;
    jQuery("body").append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
    jQuery("body").append(construct_code());
    jQuery.getScript("//connect.facebook.net/" + a + "/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + lb_l_ret.appid + "&status=1&cookie=1", function(a, n, g) {
        window.setTimeout(arevicotest, 200)
    })
}
});
```

Would the entire script need to be rewritten or will simply pointing to the latest URL be enough?

Comment: `all.js` is outdated, you should use the current URL for the SDK, which has the “file” named `sdk.js`, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

That code is outdated, this would be the correct one, edited to fit your example:

```
$.getScript('https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: lb_l_ret.appid,
        version: 'v4.0'
    });
    arevicotest();
});
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/v4.0

if "a" is the language/country identifier, just use it like this:

```
$.getScript('https://connect.facebook.net/' + a + '/sdk.js', function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: lb_l_ret.appid,
        version: 'v4.0'
    });
    arevicotest();
});
```

Comment: this code works perfectly fine for me, so please add your exact code on pastebin (the new version). also, debug your code and make sure "a" is filled with something (for example "en_US"), and lb_l_ret.appid is filled with a valid app id.
`console.log(a);` and `console.log(lb_l_ret.appid);`

Comment: Here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/rfvJaYnY   The locale and appid are customized via inline javascript (posted earlier), not in the .js file.

Comment: try with the first version of my code for testing, and with a hardcoded app id instead of `lb_l_ret.appid`

Comment: also put this in the document ready function, as you can see in the facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/v4.0

Comment: With `+ a +` it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined at lightbox.js:501`. Without the `+ a +` it gives the `Uncaught b {message: "invalid version specified", innerError: undefined}` error. Adding a hardcoded app ID to either version of the code did not change the result. Using the code from your link produced these errors: https://i.imgur.com/S5k37di.png

Comment: use this exact code and replace the app id with your own one: https://pastebin.com/uM57nFvW

Comment: with the code from my link, i only meant to put the new code in the jquery ready function, not to just copy all of it blindly...

Comment: It's pretty clear that the script has to be re-written for the new SDK.  It might be using functions that are simply not present in v4.0 or have been deprecated.  You're welcome to try it yourself with your own app since you already have all the code.  The developer abandoned it.  I've spent a few days on it and have to move on.

Comment: of course, the app id is a string, so you need quotes (single or double does not make a difference in javascript). that error message means that the function you are trying to use does not exist - obviously, because did not create it. and you do not need it, it is for app login and you don't do that.

Comment: sorry, i missed the closing single quote in my pastebin, after the app id. did you try it with that exact code (and your own app id, of course)? > https://pastebin.com/F8pGGfzv

Comment: I tried it with  and without the quotation marks and with the app ID

Comment: and you are sure you are testing the correct/new code, and not the old one? that error is very specific and did not change in any way. did you remove/replace the old code or is it still there?

Comment: Look, I may not know javascript because I never needed to learn it, but I'm not an idiot.  Copying and pasting is not difficult.  I have been very detailed and specific in my responses about exactly what I did and what the errors were.  I tried every possible combination we have discussed. As I wrote earlier. I am moving on. The script works with older versions of the SDK, although not perfectly, but it will do. If it stops working, I'll pay someone $200 to write a new script.

Comment: hiring someone for it would probably the best option, as this goes far beyond the meaning of stackoverflow. btw, if you just bought this script recently, you should try to get your money back. it is a very old one and a complete rewrite would probably the best solution. for example, it uses the user_likes permission only for checking if the user liked a page, and you would not get through facebooks (new) review process for that.

Comment: The purpose of the plugin is to prompt people to like the page IF they haven't liked it.  If what you're saying is correct, then the plugin can't be rewritten per policy.

Comment: yeah, if that is the only purpose, then the plugin will not work in any way anymore, i am afraid. the only reliable way to detect if a user liked a page is with the user_likes permission, and you would not get it approved for that.

Comment: I don't think that's correct, because the plugin works fine, other than being occasionally buggy.  I've used this and similar scripts for many years.

Comment: if it works fine, why the question on stackoverflow? :) btw, the "edge.create" event being used for new likes (FB.login with user_likes is for existing ones) is deprecated and may still work with some very old app. but it is just a matter of time until it stops working too. main reason: like gating is not allowed and people should not get an annoying popup with "please like my page" :) - also, they should be allowed to unlike at the exact same place - not possible if you hide a like button if liked already.

Comment: You're not reading the rules correctly.  The app is not collecting data on users.  It simply checks if the user has liked the page to avoid nagging if the user has already liked it.  There is no process on Facebook for banning this.  Millions of sites use it.

Comment: sorry, i meant that like gating is not allowed according to the rules, i did not mean your script would do it ;) - in this case it is just annoying for users, but as long as the user can access every content without liking, of course it would not be breaking the rules.